# How to tell if a command is using a secure connection?

Tags: encryption

To make SQL server calls from my VM I use the command line tool `sqlcmd` however its doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16  fails to detail whether the connection it makes to the remote SQL server is secure or not

How can I tell whether an arbitrary command makes secure connections to remote servers ?

```
strace sqlcmd all-parms-go-here
```

I ran above however its not evident from looking at the trace output whether its connections are secure or not ( uses encryption like https or similar )

Would wireshark give me an answer ?

Comment: Wireshark would help. Maybe also indirectly when tracing shows that some TLS library is used. But that is no real proof compared to looking at network traffic.

Comment: from your link: "The new version of SQLCMD supports Azure AD authentication, including Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) support for SQL Database, Azure Synapse Analytics, and Always Encrypted features." and "You need version 13.1 or higher to support Always Encrypted (-g)" that's for column encryption.

Comment: `sqlcmd` uses the ODBC driver, and that determines the connection encryption: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/connect-with-strict-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So, is your question about `sqlcmd` or any other random command? Commands will say if they use encrypted connections.